# Using POST without a form in jade and node.js?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, pug

I am trying to make a delete option for some items I have in a list. The way I am doing this is to give every item in the list a button or a link of some sort that will use POST to send the _id (from mongodb). As you can see in the code below (req.body.id), I'm trying to get the id form the request. However, the request does not have the id, because I don't know how to do this without using a form and a input field.

I've seen some ways to do it with javascript in PHP. But is there a more jade and node.js specific way?

```
router.post("/deleteitem", function(req,res) {
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get("itemcollection");
  id = req.body.id;

  collection.remove({
    "_id": id
  }, function (err, removed) {
    if (err) {
      res.send("Error");
    }
    else {
      res.redirect("editlist");
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Edit:

Client-side:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1.
        Items
    ul
        each item, i in editlist
            li
                p #{item.name} costs #{item.price}
                button#btnSubmit(type="button",method="post",action="/deleteitem") Delete

    a(href="/") Back to start
```

The button part is not very relevant though. Firstly I am not sure if it's possible to do it this way. Secondly I have not included the id in any way. I was just experimenting.

One way I could probably do it is to include the id in the url as a parameter. But that seems a bit more convoluted than just using POST and including the id in the request.

Comment: Where is your client side code ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Added it. The button part is not very relevant though, since I am not sure it's possible to do it this way. I was just experimenting.

Comment: Have you tried to send the data in query parameter?

Comment: Aah, @notionquest. I just edited the main post saying that was a possibility. Thanks anyways. But I would really like to be able to do it just using POST and including the id in the request body. If that is a possibility, if not, I'll probably have to settle for your way.

Comment: I don't really get your question! You want to make an ajax request ?